# Android Studio Mark Directory as Test Sources Root

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea, android-testing

I've done something in build.gradle to remove the green highlighting of the androidTest.java package.

I don't know how to get it back.

IntelliJ has a "Mark directory as test sources root" option in the context menu but I can't find the equivalent in Android Studio.

Is there a way to define this folder so I can start testing?
(If it means anything, the test java files all have an icon of a "J" with a red circle around it)

Comment: If it's not available in the right-click menu of the project view, then it should be available in the Project Settings.  Have you looked there?

Comment: You should mark Diego's answer as correct, I tried it and it works perfectly

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can click on the folder and type `Cmd + Shift + a` to enter the action search and then by typing `Mark directory as` you will get the menu.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this option is no longer so easily available. To access it I need to double tap 'shift' and manually type "mark directory as. Then I can pick it from the list."

Comment: Actually this _is_ easily available: it is offered in the context menu of folders (right click).

Answer (score 0):

For others in case somebody do not use gradle; maybe you can do something like this:

Project Structure > Project Settings:

[image]