# Android Studio: cannot create release-specific Res folder

Tags: android-studio

My project is configured with the usual builds: *debug* and *release*.

Unfortunately I'm having troubles creating build-specific Res folders: the *debug* Res folder is created correctly, while the *release* Res folder is created as a standard folder.

The procedure I followed is:

- I selected "Project" in the top left dropdown
- Inside App\src I created two folders: *debug* and *release*.
- On each of these new folders: Right click -> New -> Folder -> Res folder -> (the correct path is shown) -> Finish

This is the result:

[image]

The Res folder inside *release* has the wrong icon.

I tried to use the *release* Res folder as is, placing the needed files in it:

[image]

Unfortunately, files in *release*\Res don't get recognized:

[image]

I tried to find a way to somhow "convert" a standard folder to a Res one, without success.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by **aiqency** I tried **ctrl+shift+a** -> **Mark Directory as** -> **Resource root**.
Folder icon changes to the right one (with orange lines), but in Android view documents are still not shown for (*release*).
If i close and reopen Android Studio, Res folder icon reverts to standard one (no orange lines).

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried to update Android Studio to the latest version (3.6.1 build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897).
Then I created a new, no-activity project.

Same behaviour...

Any clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a bug on Android Studio bug tracker.
They answered me that this is the intended behavior, this is their answer:

*Only one variant is active at the same time (generally `debug` by default), so it's normal you do not see `release/res` as an active (re)source folder.
The view in `android` mode will also only show you the resources associated with the current variant so this is expected.
You can use the variant switcher (on the left border at the bottom) to switch between release and debug.*

Answer (score 0):

It's called `Mark as Directory` and you can access it from the action search menu.

It is mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39841275/2754562)

Comment: I spoke too soon... now folder is marked as Res (orange lines in the icon), but in Android view documents are not shown...